# crontab to use wget without certificate

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

Im trying to run my crontab after adding SSL sertificate but I faced with problem:

```
 Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.***.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I see it says to use `--no-check-certificate'` but I don't know how to use it. Can anybody explain me that?

Comment: Looks like it's something to do with wget.

Comment: yes, I know, I found that I need to upgrade wget version but I don't know how

Comment: Have you checked this site: [skip certificate check](http://www.elftronix.com/how-to-automatically-skip-wget-ssl-certificate-check/) ? It might help.

Comment: @AlvinBunk yes, I did. This is not an option, I tried to deal with that, but I need it to work every time. I need to config something on the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have given very little detail on what your issue is, why you are getting the error, or what you have tried to do to solve this.

I presume you are running wget in your cron to get a local address? I presume you have also recently changed your server to configure SSL and now are getting this error?

So options are:

1. Use the --no-check-certificate option to wget.
2. Fix the error.
3. Allow http access for this wget.

The first is the easiest. If you are calling this:

```
wget https://www.example.com
```

Then change it to:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.example.com
```

That's exactly what's in the link Alvin suggested so not sure what's the problem with that? That option has been supported in wget since forever so not sure why you think it's not.

The second option depends on why wget cannot verify the issuers authority. It could be for a number of reasons:

1. You are using a server name which is not on the certificate (e.g. localhost or 127.0.0.1 or a local server name). If so you need to either ignore the error as above or change your wget command to the ServerName recognised on the cert.
2. You have your server configured incorrectly. If so see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322184/ssl-issue-warning-users-not-secure-however-ssl-applied/33322569#33322569).
3. The trust store wget uses is missing a necessary cert.

Finally we come to the third option. If you are running a wget from the cron to the same server (for example to check if your webserver is up) then it may be overkill to force that to happen over https. You might be better still allowing http for that server alone. How you would do this depends on the web server and how you have configured https for it (e.g. If you redirect all http traffic to https then you could put an exception in for requests from 127.0.0.1).